# javascript oddness when using delete

Tags: javascript

So...

```
var outObj = people[0];
outObj.oAuthID = null;
delete outObj.oAuthID;
```

Gives me...

```
{
  "uuid": "39b2b45f-1dde-4c9a-8765-1bc76f55848f",
  "oAuthID": null,
  "date": "2013-10-21T16:48:47.079Z",
  "updated": "2013-10-21T16:48:47.079Z",
  "id": "52655aefcc81bb9adc000001"
}
```

But this...

```
function clone(obj) {
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        var copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        var copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}

var outObj = clone(people[0]);
outObj.oAuthID = null;
delete outObj.oAuthID;
```

Gives me...

```
{
  "uuid": "39b2b45f-1dde-4c9a-8765-1bc76f55848f",
  "date": "2013-10-21T16:48:47.079Z",
  "updated": "2013-10-21T16:48:47.079Z",
  "id": "52655aefcc81bb9adc000001"
}
```

I **really** don't want to have to clone everything every time simply to hide a property from my results. Whats going on? What does this happen? How can I fix it to work "normal"?

Comment: That's not what I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/2PvMr/1

Comment: It might have something to do with the object's prototype chain. "If a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype chain, the object will inherit that property from the prototype." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: If `people[0]` is a custom object with prototype containig `oAuthID` then you'll get the result ( http://jsfiddle.net/qw3UV/ ). However what do you mean by "gives me", how exactly do you get that result? In console? Perhaps if you want to transfer that object somewhere then it is enough to JSON serialize/deserialize it?

Comment: @freakish - The object is converted to JSON and sent in response to a http request. The request is just logged to the browser console. I'm trying to hide information that the end user shouldn't see. I would rather then not even see the field name so I was trying to delete it. The original object that is being cloned is the result of a jugglingdb call so I'm guessing is has stuff in the prototype?

Comment: @Justin808 Ah, so you're talking about server-side JavaScript (not that it matters). I assume that you log the object? But what about the JSON string? Check if the browser actually receives the field, because there is a chance that you won't have it because by default `JSON.stringify` won't look inside the prototype. However this behaviour can be overriden by the library and in that case the only choice you have is to do the copy.

Comment: @freakish Yeah, I log the object just before I JSON.stringify it and sent to the client. the client sees the `oAuthID : null` which is what I'm trying to avoid, though its better than showing the actual ID. can I `delete` it from the prototype somehow as well?

Comment: @Justin808 You can try `delete Model.prototype.oAuthID;`. This might not work though because of prototype chaining. And even if you manage to delete that attribute you may break the library (I assume there is a reason why they created such field in prototype, normally you only put functions in prototype). And finally it seems that there is a custom JSON serialization set on that class in which case deleting a property from prototype might not help at all. My suggestion is to leave it as it is. It's not a big deal after all.

Comment: @Justin808 Both produce the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/QxqQp/ The problem will be somewhere else in your code probably...

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to know if you have tested this code in multiple browsers as they give inconsistent behavior with the `delete` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues

One thing to try is deleting the property as though the object was an array.

`delete outObj['oAuthID'];`

It *should* give a more consistent behavior.